# Maximum value of $3^x+5^x-9^x+15^x-25^x$

Tags: exponential-function, maxima-minima

> Find the maximum value of $3^x+5^x-9^x+15^x-25^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ 
> Source: KVPY SX 2012

I substituted $3^x=p$ and $5^x=q$ and got $p+q-p^2+pq-q^2$ from which I'm not able to proceed further

Comment: you can rearrange as $p + q - pq - (p-q)^2$ as $x$ increases $p + q - pq$ will turn negative... so $x = 0$ seems the solution

Comment: also check if for $x \lt 0$, the expression is less than $1$

Comment: A more tedious way to find the maximum is to express $5^x$ in terms of $3^x$ or vice-versa (I did $5^x$ in terms of $3^x$ --> $5^x = (3^{\log_3(5)})^x = (3^x)^{\log_3(5)}$).